# Is there a formula for the largest number less than $10^n$ that has 8 divisors?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Find a general formula for the largest number less than $10^n$ for $n > 1$ that has exactly $8$ divisors.

I was wondering if there was a way to find a general formula for this or if it is possible to create one.

For example, for $n = 2$, $88 = 2^3 \times 11$ is the largest number less than $10^2$ that has $8$ divisors.

Comment: Do you mean eight prime divisors, eight distinct divisors, or just any kind of divisors?  So for example does $9$ have one or two or three divisors?

Comment: I mean any kind of divisors. For example, the number $9$ has $3$ positive divisors.

Comment: Yes Dietrich, I fixed that.

Comment: No, it is $88$.

Comment: This is [OEIS A182676](https://oeis.org/A182676).

Comment: That is for an $n$ digit, so it has the potential of nonexistence. I am asking for any number of digits.

Comment: There is always (for $n > 1$) a prime between $\frac{10^{n-1}}{8}$ and $\frac{10^n}{8}$, so there always exists an $n$-digit number with eight divisors.

Comment: How does that imply there always exists an $n$-digit number with eight divisors?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ have prime factorization $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$.

Let $\tau(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{k} (a_i+1)$, the count-of-divisors function.

There are three cases if $\tau(x) = 8$:

$\tau(x) = (a_1+1) = (8) = 8$

$\tau(x) = (a_1+1)(a_2+1) = (2)(4) = 8$

$\tau(x) = (a_1+1)(a_2+1)(a_3+1) = (2)(2)(2) = 8$

This implies that $x$ is of the form $p^7$, $pq^3$, or $pqr$, where $p,q,r$ are distinct. So we can find the largest way to represent each of these under the limit $10^n$ and then take the maximum of the three.

In practice, it's probably a lot easier to start at $10^n-1$, iterate downward, and compute $\tau(n)$ as you go until you find something with $\tau(x) = 8$.

Comment: Is it possible to find the maximum of these using a closed-form expression and not a computer?

Comment: @user19405892 For $n \geq 4$, maximal solutions appear to be in the form $pqr$, which might make sense intuitively / probabilistically, but it may not be true for all $n \geq 4$. Even if it were, there is no known closed form for finding maximal $pqr$.